# How to connect .asmx web services in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

Hi guys i'm trying to connect asmx web services in Eclipse Enterprice Edition. i cant make it .it wants to wsdl. Any help will be appreciated.I just want to be client of the web services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is any URL like service.asmx?wsdl available? Because it stores the required WSDL, as far as I know.

Comment: url includes just service.asmx.